# Php Swift Mailer: How to convert "name" <email> into format that Swift Message accepts?

Tags: php, regex, smtp, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send mail using SwiftMailer. My problem is the format in which I'm getting the `from` and `to` address is like this:

```
$from = '"first last" <email@domain.com>';
```

But when I use this

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()->setFrom($from);
```

I get the following error:

```
Address in mailbox given ["first last" <email@domain.com>] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2
```

I think it is because Swift mailer excepts the format to be

```
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()->setFrom(['email@domain.com' => 'First Last']);
```

So my question is how do I convert

```
    "first last" <email@domain.com> => ['email@domain.com' => 'First Last']
```

I can use *regex* but there can be many cases like if quotes are not present, if email is with and without angular brackets, etc?

What is the best most foolproof way to do this?

*Edit: Adding some more info for clarification*

The `from` and `to` email are what the users are saving in the database, they are coming in many formats like `"name" <email>`, `name <email>`, `<email>`, or sometimes just `email`. **I want to normalize all these string inputs to something that I can pass to `Swift_Message::newInstance()->setFrom` function**

Comment: `$from = "first last" <email@domain.com>;` is a syntax error. What's your *actual* code?

Comment: From where does this string come? There is no way to check if everything is present before sending it?

Comment: actually `$from` comes from database but the format is like this only.. I've corrected the syntax. The actual code is pretty much this `$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()->setFrom('"first last" <email@domain.com>');`

Comment: @Sakuto: the `from` and `to` email are what the users are saving in the database, they are coming in many formats like `"name" <email>`, `name <email>`, `<email>`, or sometimes just `email`. I want to normalize all these inputs to something that I can pass to `Swift_Message::newInstance()->setFrom` function